# Nested Navigation not works in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**Nested Navigation not works**

App.js
Components
    Reports
    Dashboard
        SideBar

**SideBar Code**

```
export default class SideBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <List...                
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Reports')}>
                  <Text>{data}</Text>
                </ListItem>
              );
            }}
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

**Dashboard Code**

```
 <Drawer 
  ref={(ref) => {this.drawer = ref; }}
  content={<SideBar/>}
  onClose={()=> this.closeDrawer()}>
```

**App.js Code**

```
    import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import SideBar from './src/components/SideBar';

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
  Logout: {screen:SigninTabs, 
    navigationOptions: {
     header: null
    }},
  Dashboard: {screen:Dashboard,
  navigationOptions:{
    header: null,
  }},
  Reports: {screen:Reports,
   navigationOptions:{
title:'Reports',
}  },
},
));
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
  }
}
  render(){
    return (
      <AppNavigator/>
  );
}}
export default App;
```

How i can navigate from sidebar to reports, sidebar is imported in dashboard and dashboard is imported in app.js

Answer (score 0):

Sidebar needs to be added in your navigation stack for this.props.navigation to work.